# Piwik not running in Phonegap Apps

Tags: cordova, browser, analytics, matomo

I'm using Piwik to analyse the user-actions on my sites, and everything is working fine when the site is shown up in the browser (on PC, Mac, and phone browser).

But when I surf to the same pages (with the piwik code inside) inside a PhoneGap app, the app is loading and loading and loading and displays in the end... nothing.

What's wrong there? JavaScript is enabled. Is there a known problem, and is Google Analytics the better alternative?

Thanks.

Comment: oops, I've been here before... would vote up again if I could

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. Any one have any idea about this <access origin="*"/> has been placed properly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you blocked piwik's tracker url inside your phonegap config.xml?

Try to add this to your config.xml:

```
<access origin="*"/>
```